# OpenMP and irregular tree optimization

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

I have a pretty simple example of what I want:

```
#include "vector"
#include "omp.h"
#include <ctime>
#include "windows.h"//just for Sleep

class MyItem
{
public:
    MyItem()
    {
    }
    void createChildren()
    {
        Sleep(10);
        int childCount = (rand()%5);
        if(childCount>3) //25% of chance of having 4 children 75% of having no children
        {
            for(int i=0; i<childCount;i++)
                children.push_back(MyItem());
        }
    }
    std::vector<MyItem> children;
};

double calculateTree()
{
    srand(0);
    std::vector<MyItem> toMakePartition;
    for(int i=0;i<250;i++)
       toMakePartition.push_back(MyItem());

    size_t totalSize = toMakePartition.size();
    int currentDone = 0;

    clock_t begin = clock();
    while (currentDone < totalSize)
    {
        omp_set_num_threads(omp_get_num_procs());
        #pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic)
        for (int index = currentDone; index < totalSize; index++)
        {
            toMakePartition[index].createChildren();
            #pragma omp critical
            {
                for(int i=0; i<toMakePartition[index].children.size();i++)
                    toMakePartition.push_back(toMakePartition[index].children[i]);
                currentDone++;
                totalSize = toMakePartition.size();
            }
        }
        printf("STEP DONE, currentDone %i totalSize %i\n", currentDone, (int)totalSize);
    }

    clock_t end = clock();
    double elapsed_secs = double(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("TOTAL TIME %f\n",(float)elapsed_secs);
    return elapsed_secs;
}
```

It runs in 1.368 seconds with OpenMP and that's not bad but a bit suboptimal, let me explain why:

I get this as output

> STEP DONE, currentDone 250 totalSize 374 STEP DONE, currentDone 374
>   totalSize 478 STEP DONE, currentDone 478 totalSize 586 STEP DONE,
>   currentDone 586 totalSize 630 STEP DONE, currentDone 630 totalSize 654
>   STEP DONE, currentDone 654 totalSize 686 STEP DONE, currentDone 686
>   totalSize 750 STEP DONE, currentDone 750 totalSize 810 STEP DONE,
>   currentDone 810 totalSize 846 STEP DONE, currentDone 846 totalSize 902
>   STEP DONE, currentDone 902 totalSize 934 STEP DONE, currentDone 934
>   totalSize 966 STEP DONE, currentDone 966 totalSize 982 STEP DONE,
>   currentDone 982 totalSize 982

this means that the for is executed with the previous value of totalSize per each thread and it is only updated once the for loop is ended and evaluates the the while loop again, I know that this has sense according to how OpenMP works, but if I could update it inside for loop it could be great specially since in my real case some branches could take x1000 the time of other branches, I think that this is impossible but maybe some of you could give me a tip to evaluate another possible improvement here.

Btw I'm using MSVS 2017 so making OpenMP tasks is not an option.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Openmp 2.0 can't do it. Make a thread pool with a task queue yourself.

Comment: @JerryCoffin this is just an example, in my actual case I have no random values but they are based on of heuristics using the data that the class contains.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark unfortunatly as I said OpenMP tasks are not supported by OpenMP 2 that is used in msvs.